# pgAdmin fails to execute an sql statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm an novice in pgSQL, so I'm executing different sql commends - here is next one - I want to get count of affected rows by the last sql command:

```
 delete from "Menu" where "ID" = 0;
 GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT;
 select integer_var;
```

but pgAdmin says:

```
 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GET"
 LINE 1: GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT;
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this command can only be run in the context of PL/pgSQL code, not just arbitrary statements you run in pgAdmin.

Comment: hmmm.. so then there is no way to achive affected row count using pgAdmin?

Comment: Well, at a minimum, you could create a plpqsql stored procedure, although my guess is that you'd have to pass the SQL insert statement to execute as a parameter, and have the procedure execute it dynamically.

Comment: @DreadAngel - Yup, you'd have to write a function and then execute that from pgAdmin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with PostgreSQL 9.0 you can use [DO](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-do.html) to execute anonymous code blocks

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    integer_var integer;
BEGIN
    delete from "Menu" where "ID"  = 0;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT;
    raise notice 'Rows removed: %', integer_var;
END$$;
```

I replaced the last select with a notice because I wasn't complete sure what you wanted to do with the result of that select and this way was the easiest to illustrate DO.

If this is in the end going to be incorporated in some program you probably have the possibility to retrieve the number of affected rows directly. libpq contains the function PQcmdTuples which returns the number of rows affected. PHP has the function pg_affected_rows and in JDBC executeUpdate returns the number of rows affected.